# JQuery forEach() print out each one separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I want each **item** to be in its own `<tr>` and append to the `<tbody>`.

my code prints them all out in the same `<tr>`.

```
ingredientsArray.forEach(function(item){
    var ingredient =`<tr>
                      <td><input class="ingredientsInput" value="`+ item +`"/></td>
                    </tr>`;

    $(ingredient).appendTo('tbody');
    console.log(item);
});
```

**Resolved!** The problem was the Array was ONE long String var ingredientsArray = ["a, b, c"]; it looks like a big array but in essence it only has one param.

Comment: could you provide a working jsfiddle demo?

Comment: its working. check your code in fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/6f8e0ud9/

Comment: code will work fine. so what's not working? any error in your browser console? what is there in `ingredientsArray`?

Comment: Also, if you're using ES6 syntax, take full advantage of it. E.g.: `const ingredient =\`<tr><td><input class="ingredientsInput" value="${item}"/></td></tr>\`;`

Comment: Morris Sal  it seems that you are using `(tilt)`  rather than single quotes arround `<tr>`. Is it a TYPO mistake or you actually have that in your code? if yes convert that to single quote and it will worked

Comment: Try to make sure your questions are right

Answer (score 0):

Outsitlde the loop do `var ingredient`

Then inside do `ingredient += yourTableRowString`

Then after the loop is finished do the append

This way you only append once after your html is generated.

If you need to check the value you can always log the full string before you append.